# The "drawStars" challenge

Tags: javascript

This code:

```
function drawStars(){
    for (var i = 1; i < 4; i = i + 1){
        console.log('*');
        for (var l = 1; l < 6; l = l + 1){
            console.log('*');
        }
     }
}
```

once run, prints stars into the console.

My question is, how can I make it print a 5 by 2 pattern of starts into the console if I type in `drawStars(5,2)` into the console?

It should also be able to print other patterns corresponding to what I type into the console.

P.S. Can you also fix the unnecessary stars in between the other stars?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add parameters in your method and use them in them as the loop end-conditions. Also, the unncessary stars are the one you draw in the first loop only. Here the `p` parameter is the `pattern`.

```
function drawStars(x, y, p){
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++){
        var line = ""
        for (var j = 0; j < y; j++){
            line += p;
        }
        console.log(line);
     }
}
```

If you call it

```
drawStars(5, 2, '#')
```

Then it will output a 5x2 rectangle filled with `#`:

```
##
##
##
##
##
```

Comment: Your answer is not doing what your saying it does.